# R code incredibly slow

Tags: r, performance, loops

Recently I have been working on some R scripts to do some reports. One of the tasks involved is to check if a value in a column matches any row of another dataframe. If this is true, then set a **new column** with logical TRUE/FALSE.

More specifically, I need help improving this code chunk:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1$Id)) {
  df1 <- within(df1, newCol <- df1$Id %in% df2$Id)
}
df1$newCol <- as.factor(df1$newCol)
```

The dataset has about 10k rows so it does not make sense to need 6 minutes (tested with `proc.time()` to execute it completely, which is what it is currently happening. Also, I need to do so other types of checking, so I really need to get this right.

What am I doing wrong there that is devouring time to accomplish?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code is vectorized - there is no need for the `for` loop. In this case, you can tell because *you don't even use `i` inside the loop*. If you have 10k rows then you are running the complete operation 10k times.  If you delete the `for` wrapper around your functional line, `df1 <- within(df1, newCol <- df1$Id %in% df2$Id)`, you should get ~10k times speed-up.

Comment: Wow, that's what you got for being newbie in R :-) Thanks! that solved the issue and made sense - thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Gregor, post comments as answer ... ?

Comment: True, so that I can give the deserved credit ;)

Comment: Does code return desired results? Interestingly you never used the iterator variable, `i`, so you do the same operation multiple times! Remove the `for` but keep middle and you have a vectorized operation!

Comment: And yes, this solved the issue. Tested with first comment and now tested with the second comment and solved - otherwise, I'd be arguing it wasn't working properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is vectorized - there is no need for the for loop. In this case, you can tell because *you don't even use `i` inside the loop*. This means your loop is executing the exact same code for the exact same result 10k times. If you delete the for wrapper around your functional line

```
df1 <- within(df1, newCol <- df1$Id %in% df2$Id)
```

you should get ~10k times speed-up.

One other comment is that the point of within is to avoid re-typing a data frame's name inside. So you're missing the point by using `df1$` inside `within()`, and your data frame name is so short that it is longer to type `within()` in this case. Your entire code could be simplified to one line:

```
df1$newCol = factor(df1$Id %in% df2$Id)
```

My last comment I'm making from a state of ignorance about your application, so take it with a grain of salt, but a binary variable is almost always nicer to have as boolean (TRUE/FALSE) or integer (1/0) than as a factor. It does depend what you're doing with it, but I would leave the `factor()` off until necessary.